# How to find raw data sets for engineering?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statistics, data

For one of my courses the teachers asked me to find two samples of 30 or queries of data, and I was thinking on how I could begin to search it?

Most of the scientific articles that i looked for just show the data into graphs or simplified, but that's not really what I'm looking for, any help into how i could begin to start searching for it?

Answer (score 2):

Search for *daily maximum and minimum temperatures* for your local region. If there is a river nearby, search for *river level* or *river gauge height*. If it rains, search for *annual rainfall* in your region.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a graph that you want to get data from - to plot it differently for example, then DataThief is a handy option.

Works on many systems, and no I am not associated, but found it years ago.

Can be found :

https://datathief.org/